# How Can I open an application without login if one being opened already?

Tags: react-native

I have 5 different applications developed in react-native, I want give a better experience to my users, so if an application being logged I want the next one not to need to do login again if it is called from within the logged-in app.
How Can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a lot of ways to do this, for me i use Redux for storing the Auth Token which i generate by Random string function, and i use 2 type of Stack 1) App Stack 2) Auth stack. So before that i wrap it inside a condition where it says `{ loginKey ?<AppStack/>:<AuthStack/> }` where **appStack** is all the apps screens, **AuthStack** is login/signup screen and loginKey is redux state which stores the key one time (which we generate on successful login/signup).
Other way is as mentioned in above answer using user - login state and check if login state is true then show user your main apps screen else show user login screen.